# Python str mapping permutation with some limitations and special conditions using recursion

Tags: python, string, recursion

Given a string as input I need to change the a's to t's, c's to g's, u's to a's and g's to c's [ a-t, c-g, g-c, u-a ]. And another special condition is that there can be at most of two instances where u's convert to g's and/or g's convert to t's [ u-g, g-t].

As as example -

```
input : 
    auugca
output : 
    taacgt
    tgacgt
    taatgt
    tggcgt
    tgatgt
    tagtgt
```

In the output,

1. No special changes
2. One special change 2nd character u to g
3. One special change 3rd character u to g
4. One special change 4th character g to t
5. Two special changes 2nd and 3rd character
6. Two special changes 2nd and 4th character
7. Two special changes 3rd and 4th character

I thought of it like this,

- start from the beginning of the string
- convert a-t and c-g.
- If u or g is found, check how many specials have been previously
  encountered, if less than two, then treat as special, increment
  previously encountered counter, create two new searches recursively from the next location of the string one with special considered and other not

The code that I came up with is(in Python) -

```
 # mirna is the string to be converted
 # wobblecount is the number of specials coneverted
 # location is from which location of the string the convertion will start
 # compliment is the end string to be created


 def createonewobble(mirna, location, wobblecount, compliment):

    for counter in range(location, len(mirna)):
        if (mirna[counter] == 'A' or mirna[counter] == 'a'):
            compliment = compliment + "t"
        elif (mirna[counter] == 'C' or mirna[counter] == 'c'):
            compliment = compliment + "g"
        elif ((mirna[counter] == 'U' or mirna[counter] == 'u') and (wobblecount < 2)):
            compliment = compliment + "g"
            createonewobble(mirna, counter+1 , wobblecount+1, compliment)
            compliment = compliment + "a"
            createonewobble(mirna, counter+1 , wobblecount, compliment)
        elif ((mirna[counter] == 'G' or mirna[counter] == 'g') and (wobblecount < 2)):
            compliment = compliment + "t"
            createonewobble(mirna, counter+1 , wobblecount+1, compliment)
            compliment = compliment + "a"
            createonewobble(mirna, counter+1 , wobblecount, compliment)
        elif ((mirna[counter] == 'U' or mirna[counter] == 'u') and (wobblecount == 2)):
            compliment = compliment + "a"
        elif ((mirna[counter] == 'G' or mirna[counter] == 'g') and (wobblecount == 2)):
            compliment = compliment + "c"

    print compliment


mirna = "auugca"
createonewobble(mirna, 0, 0, "")
```

Output

```
tggcgt
tggatgt
tggatagt
tggatagt
tggatgt
tggatagt
tggatagt
tgagtgt
tgagtagt
tgagtagt
tgagatgt
tgagatagt
tgagatagt
tgagatgt
tgagatagt
tgagatagt
tgagtgt
tgagtagt
tgagtagt
tgagatgt
tgagatagt
tgagatagt
tgagatgt
tgagatagt
tgagatagt
```

This is giving me 25 outputs, with not a single correct one and also some are of length a lot more than the size of the string. Where am I going wrong ?

Comment: Your code references `createonewobble`, but doesn't define it. Please create the shortest possible **complete** program that demonstrates the problem. Please copy-paste (never retype) that program into your question, along with the expected and actual output. See [mcve] for more information.

Comment: @Rob, sorry, i changed the name of the function to convert to make it more readable but forgot to do that in recursive calls. Sorry again.

Comment: Please run the code as it stands now and copy-paste the actual and expected result into your question.

Comment: Your logic has some issues. Besides the obvious typo of accidentally using `convert` as the name of the function instead of `createonewobble`, consider that each time you encounter a `'g'` or a `'u'` you're creating two new searches in addition to the one you're presently running. This is why you're getting lots of extras. You can make things a lot clearer by doing something like `lowmirna = mirna.lower()` before you enter your loop and getting rid of nearly half of your comparisons, and using a list to track compliments rather than printing them so it's clear what's coming from where.

Comment: @Feneric, I don't get what you are asking me to do with the second half of the string.

Comment: @Robᵩ, Since there were no correct results, I didn't think giving the output will be of any importance.

Comment: Why is there more than one output? Seems like after applying all rules there should be only one.

Comment: @martineau, there will be at most 2 special conversions. Read the description of the desired output.

Comment: I did, and assumed that from that point on no further ones of that kind would be done, which leads to one result.

Comment: If 2 special conversions are made others will be general, but among all possible special conversions which ones week happen that can only be figured of all u and g are specially converted once.

Comment: At most 2, so 0 special, all possible 1 special, all possible 2 specials

Comment: @daddyodevil It looks like someone else already clarified, but the simplification presented there is what I was trying to describe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you are trying to solve here is a kind of recursion with track-back with some limitations.

Your code is close to the solution but:

1. It is not Pythonic and so hard to understand. Next time improve your readability.
2. When you tackle a permutation problem you should use a `set` to avoid duplicates. In your solution you used `print` which will give you duplicate prints (if there are any).
3. **Most importantly** when you called the recursive function you pass it the `compliment` variable which was modified before and now is not valid anymore.

To explain *point number 3* let's take a look at your code:

```
elif ((mirna[counter] == 'G' or mirna[counter] == 'g') and (wobblecount < 2)):
        compliment = compliment + "t"
        createonewobble(mirna, counter+1 , wobblecount+1, compliment)
        compliment = compliment + "a"
        createonewobble(mirna, counter+1 , wobblecount, compliment)
```

Here for example, assuming that `compliment = X` thus far, you call `createonewobble` for the first time with `compliment = Xt` and for the second time with `compliment = Xta` which I'm sure is not what you intended.

#### A working solution:

```
def create_one_wobble(options, mirna, wobble_count, compliment):

    mirna = mirna.lower()

    if wobble_count == 2:
        for letter in mirna:
            if letter == 'a':
                compliment += 't'
            elif letter == 'c':
                compliment += 'g'
            elif letter == 'g':
                compliment += 'c'
            else:
                compliment += 'a'
        options.append(compliment)

    else:
        for index, letter in enumerate(mirna):
            if letter == 'a':
                compliment += 't'
            elif letter == 'c':
                compliment += 'g'
            elif letter == 'g':
                create_one_wobble(options, mirna[index+1:], wobble_count + 1, compliment + "t")
                create_one_wobble(options, mirna[index+1:], wobble_count + 1, compliment + "c")
                compliment += 'c'
            elif letter == 'u':
                create_one_wobble(options, mirna[index+1:], wobble_count + 1, compliment + "g")
                create_one_wobble(options, mirna[index+1:], wobble_count + 1, compliment + "a")
                compliment += 'a'

permutations = []
mirna = "auugca"
create_one_wobble(permutations, mirna, 0, "")
permutations = sorted(list(set(permutations)))
for a in permutations:
    print(a)
```

Prints out:

```
taacgt
taatgt
tagcgt
tagtgt
tgacgt
tgatgt
tggcgt
```

#### Edit:

Regarding *point number 1*.
It is clear (to me at least) that you have some background in programming and the ideas of algorithms and functions are not entirely new to you.

Having said that, it is quite obvious that you are somewhat new to Python.

Python should be an easy to write - easy to understand language.
A "pythonic code" is a piece of code that is written as simple as can be utilizing  the power of the standard library of Python.

1. **Understanding the types in Python.**

   ```
   for counter in range(location, len(mirna)):
   ```

   This line of code uses indexes to iterate over a string. In Python a
   string is already an `iterable` object. That means you can just do
   this:

   ```
   for letter in word:
   ```

   And assuming that `word` is a string, everything will go as planned.
2. **Readability.**

   ```
   if (mirna[counter] == 'A' or mirna[counter] == 'a'):
   ```

   This line of code is used to decide the content of the `mirna` string in the `counter` place and handles both uppercase and lowercase cases.

   I bet that you will agree with me that

   ```
   if letter == 'a':
   ```

   is much more readable. So in combo with my previous note, all you have to do beforehand is `mirna = mirna.lower()` which will make all letters lowercase and reduce the number of comparisons by half (this 'half' prediction is not *entirely* correct but you get the idea).
3. **Use built in mechanisms.**

   ```
   createonewobble(mirna, counter+1 , wobblecount+1, compliment)
   ```

   This line passes the whole string as a parameter plus a numeric parameter which tells the function from where to start. The best practice here is to use `slices`. This mechanism allows you to pass only a `slice` or a window if you will, of the original string. That way you don't need the extra numeric parameter.
   If I want the next call to the function to iterate over the string starting from the `counter+1` location I can just do:

   ```
   createonewobble(mirna[counter + 1:], wobblecount+1, compliment)
   ```

   This syntax means `[from:to]` and when one of them is omitted that means from the start \ all the way to the end. [More on slices](https://docs.python.org/3.5/tutorial/introduction.html#lists).
4. [Naming conventions](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#naming-conventions) is something else you should read about.

#### Summing up

There is plenty more and even the more experienced ones with Python learn a thing or two every day.
I really recommend [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/). That is the best place to sharpen your Python writing skills.

Comment: Its almost 2 a.m. here and I just woke up to drink water and saw your answer, seems like its correct. Thanks a ton man. I'll check it up tomorrow morning. And till then if you would kindly elaborate on point number 1 that you said about my logic / program not being pythonic and how do i make my code more readable. Again thanks a lot. I dont know about sets in python but i'll surely look em up.

Comment: Thanks for help and advice. It works. I'll look into the things you said. This code is a part of a bigger program program, this is just one of it's functions. I'll put up my code for review once it's done. And you were also bang on on the fact that I know programming a bit but just some syntax of Python.
Good morning.

Comment: I completed it and posted it for review. Please check it out   https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/172673/146389